# Pandas Propagate Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

newbie here.
Working whith Pandas

I have this df

| SPT.ant | Dif_Sig | Order_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | True | Nan |
| 19297 | True | 19297 |
| 19297 | False | 0 |
| 19302 | False | 0 |
| 19350 | True | 19350 |
| 19345 | False | 0 |
| 19355 | False | 0 |
| 19360 | False | 0 |

The way "Order_Price" is calculated is :
df['Order_Price'] = df['SPT.ant'] * df['Dif_Sig']

and need to propagate de value of  "Order_Price" from row 2 "19297" and row 5 "19350" utill a new value is diferent to 0

so the table would result

| SPT.ant | Dif_Sig | Order_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | True | Nan |
| 19297 | True | 19297 |
| 19297 | False | 19297 |
| 19302 | False | 19297 |
| 19350 | True | 19350 |
| 19345 | False | 19350 |
| 19355 | False | 19350 |
| 19360 | False | 19350 |

it would be ok to have this in another column as well, whatever is easier.

| SPT.ant | Dif_Sig | Order_Price | Position_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | True | Nan | Nan |
| 19297 | True | 19297 | 19297 |
| 19297 | False | 0 | 19297 |
| 19302 | False | 0 | 19297 |
| 19350 | True | 19350 | 19350 |
| 19345 | False | 0 | 19350 |
| 19355 | False | 0 | 19350 |
| 19360 | False | 0 | 19350 |

I would like to input the values without having to iterate de df but dont know if posible.
I tried many ways but got even more confused now.

Any help would apreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to forward fill the zeros (ffill method)

```
df['Position_Price'] =  df['Order_Price'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```